# Using the CASE statement on one column and calculating the aggregate of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to use the case statement on one column and calculate an aggregate of another column if the condition is satisfied.

A sample data table (for a hotel, for example) that I am querying looks like so:

```
|  date  | customer_name | customer_id | expense_type | billed_amount |
|  08-02 |   John Doe    |      1      |   personal   |     120.00    |
|  08-03 |   John Doe    |      1      |   personal   |      80.00    |
|  08-04 |   John Doe    |      1      |   corporate  |     205.00    |
|  08-02 |   Adam Smith  |      2      |   corporate  |     400.00    |
|  08-03 |   Adam Smith  |      2      |   personal   |     300.00    |
|  08-06 |   Adam Smith  |      2      |   corporate  |     150.00    |
```

Below is the SQL query I wrote:

```
Select
    customer_name
    , customer_id
    , case when expense_type = 'personal' then sum(billed_amount) else 0 end as personal_bill
    , case when expense_type = 'corporate' then sum(billed_amount) else 0 end as corporate_bill
From payments
Where date > '08-01'
Group by 1, 2
```

The error message I get is:

```
Column "expense_type" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

When I try to group column 3 as well (along with 1 and 2), I get this error message:

```
Aggregates not allowed in GROUP BY clause
```

Finally, below illustrates the desired resulting table:

```
| customer name | customer_id | personal_bill | corporate_bill |
|   John Doe    |      1      |     200.00    |     205.00     |
|   Adam Smith  |      2      |     300.00    |     550.00     |
```

One solution I can think of is creating two different subqueries that constrain the "expense_type" in the Where section (i.e. where expense_type = 'personal') and then querying them in the master query, but that's a lot of similar code with one line of difference. Could you please help me write this query in an efficient manner? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter`:

```
select
    customer_name,
    customer_id,
    sum(billed_amount) filter (where expense_type = 'personal') as personal_bill,
    sum(billed_amount) filter (where expense_type = 'corporate') as corporate_bill
from payments
where date > '08-01'
group by 1, 2

 customer_name | customer_id | personal_bill | corporate_bill 
---------------+-------------+---------------+----------------
 Adam Smith    |           2 |        300.00 |         550.00
 John Doe      |           1 |        200.00 |         205.00
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum the entire `CASE` expression:

```
select
    customer_name,
    customer_id,
    sum(case when customer_type = 'personal'
             then billed_amount else 0 end) as personal_bill
    sum(case when customer_type = 'corporate'
             then billed_amount else 0 end) as corporate_bill
from payments
where date > '08-01'
group by 1, 2
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer - this is probably closest to what i was looking for, but selecting the other answer with "filter" because it's a new concept that i learned through this question

Comment: @Joe I didn't know about this either.  Of note, the accepted answer would not run on any other database.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
Select MIN(customer_name) AS customer_name, customer_id,
       SUM(case when expense_type = 'personal' then billed_amount::double precision else 0 end) as personal_bill, 
       SUM(case when expense_type = 'corporate' then billed_amount::double precision else 0 end) as corporate_bill
From payments
Where date > '08-01'
Group by customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer - this is very close to what i was looking for, but selecting the other answer with "filter" because it's a new concept that i learned through this question

Comment: Okay Sure... @Joe